# Pull from List Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set list that is frequently changed. Example shown below:

```
A1 AEZS
A2 AEMD
A3 EARS
A4 BCT
A5 BSTG
A6 CHFS
A7 BPMX
A8 ABCD
A9 ZERNA
A10 APPL
```

I want to extract from this list to pull the words that start with the letter "A", and make it into another list. From my research, I'm aware that using the following function.

Below is the end result I would like to do (C column is arbitrary):

```
C1 AEZS
C2 AEMD
C3 ABCD
C4 APPL
```

How can I do this? 
I'm aware that using the formula `=IF(LEFT("A",1)....etc` is probably a good start. But I am new to Excel, and I am not too familiar to working with it. Additionally, I would like to be able to keep the cells in their each row (as in not all into one cell)

Comment: This sounds pretty straightforward use of AutoFilter to then filter by "Begins with". You don't specify how you are going to "pull" your data. From what and into what? Makes a big difference on what assistance can be provided.

Comment: Pull data from List and extract only needed words that begin with letter A

Comment: What does pull mean? Extract to what? How will this process be completed operationally? Will someone click a button? Copy and paste manually? You've used exactly the same words to re-explain. What I'm trying to convey is that your references are ambiguous misnomers. They don't actually explain what the intent is. Hence you receive numerous answers that could all be correct but vary wildly. Hope this helps you in future postings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array formula (entered with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>).

If your info (`AEZS`, `AEMD`, etc.) is in column A, starting row 1, you can put this in say `B1` and drag down:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$10,SMALL(IF(LEFT($A$1:$A$10,1)="A",ROW($A$1:$A$10)-ROW(A$1)+1),ROWS(A$1:A1)))
```

Then, to hide errors, just wrap `IFERROR([above formula],"")` around it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using Array formulas by using the `AGGREGATE` function.  It might also be handy to put the "starting letter" in a cell so it can be changed. For example, with your data in `myRange` in column A and the starting letters in the first row,

```
B2:  =IFERROR(INDEX(myRange,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/1/(LEFT(myRange)= B$1)*ROW(myRange),ROWS($1:1))),"")
```

Select B2 and fill across as far as needed (eg to Bn)

Then select B2:Bn and fill down as far as needed.

[image]

To understand how this is working, I suggest you use Excel's built-in HELP feature, and also the formula evaluator tool.

And, of course, if this does not need to be dynamic, you can always use a simple or advanced filter.  Again, these are well explained in HELP.

Comment: So myRange in this acse would be A2:A11? Just the list I am pulling from?

Comment: @Friezan Actually, because we are looking at the actual row number, and not the row in the data array, it needs to include $A$1.  But it can extend past $A$11.  As a matter of fact, you can even use the entire column $A:$A, but that slows down the computation.

Comment: @Friezan To clarify further, the row number being returned is the absolute row number; the INDEX function calls for the row number within the table itself, where the first row of data is row 1.  So if the table starts at row 10, and the match is on Row 11, the row_argument for the Index function needs to be 1.  So one needs to subtract the row number of the Headers from the row calculation result in order to get the proper row.  If the table starts with headers in row 1, that can be done by just extending the range.  If it starts in a different row, that computation needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

Advance Filter offers something of the capability, though is not dynamic:

Add a label to ColumnA and a criterion in A2:

```
="=A*"
```

Then DATA > Sort & Filter, Advanced and select *Copy to another location*, select ColumnA for *List range:*, `A1:A2` for *Criteria range:* and *Copy to:* wherever suits.

Advance Filter remembers those settings (except, strangely, *Copy to another location*) so if the contents of ColumnA change it is only a few clicks to call up Advanced Filter again, select *Copy ...* and <kbd>OK</kbd>.